# Why ${A \subseteq P(A) }$ false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let's say I have a set ${A = \{1, 2\}}$, so ${P(A) = \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}, \varnothing\}}$

So, I can say that ${\{1, 2\} \subseteq \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}, \varnothing\}}$

What is wrong?

Comment: It's not false.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) , *In mathematics, the power set (or powerset) of any set S is the set of all subsets of S, including the empty set and* **S itself**

Comment: Why you think it's wrong$?$ You can clearly see that it is correct

Comment: $1,2$ are not members of $P(A)$, so $\{1,2\}$ is not a subset. You could correctly say that $\{1,2\}\in P(A)$ or that $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\subseteq P(A)$.

Comment: $\varnothing\subseteq P(\varnothing)$ is true.

Comment: $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ is false in general—I don't know why the comments saying it's not false are being up-voted.

Comment: A set $A$ satisfying $A\subseteq P(A)$ is called [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set). For example, von Neumann ordinals are transitive sets, hence they satisfy $A\subseteq P(A)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What $\{ 1, 2 \} \subseteq \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \varnothing \}$ means is that $1 \in \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \varnothing \}$ and $2 \in \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \varnothing \}$.

But $1$ is not an element of $\{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \varnothing \}$ (and neither is $2$).

Don't let the fact that $\{ 1 \} \in \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \varnothing \}$ fool you, since $1 \ne \{ 1 \}$.

Note that $\{ 1, 2 \} \in \mathcal{P}(\{ 1, 2 \})$ is true, though.

In fact, $A \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ is true for all sets $A$, since $A \subseteq A$.

Sets $A$ such that $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ are called [*transitive sets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set).

Comment: Can you be more explicit when you say $1\neq \{1\}$?

Comment: A box with a ball inside is a different thing than just the ball. (In this analogy the set $\{a,b,c\}$ is a box containing the things $a$, $b$ and $c$.)